# Get 400 (empty response) when sending multi-part form to django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an existing Django app and need to be able to upload a file.

I'm sending it a multi-part form so I can send a file and some fields, but the server I get back a 400, but the server errors silently and keeps running.

How can I allow my view to accept a multi-part form?

My route function definition is simply:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def upload(request, pk)
    print "hello"
```

It doesn't get to hello, so somewhere in the magical box of Django this JSON error is occuring. Can anyone give me a clue where to look? I've checked our urls.py file and see nothing that would make this decision or interrupt a request and our **init**.py file is empty. runserver isn't even a file... I guess it's just more django magic.

(Python: 2.7, Django: 1.10.6)

Comment: I tried added MultiPartParser to DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES in settings.py, but I still get  a silent 400.

Comment: It's working now. I had to remove the accept and Content-Type headers.

Something magical in Django was silently failing on those I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I was sending the request with a Content-Type header as form multipart, once I removed that header my request was being accepted again.

When I removed the header, a boundary field was added to content-type and I suppose that was necessary for Django to not fail silently.

I'm still not sure why Django failed silently.